# Trigger dynamic dropdown to load

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I'm very new to scripting stuff, but here's what I'm trying to do. When visiting a webpage, there are two dropdowns available, but the second is disabled until a selection is made in the first. The content of the second populates automatically as soon as something is selected in the first, and each option in the first leads to a unique set of options in the second. I'm attempting to automate selecting items in both. I can set a value in the first using `"document.getElementById('firstDropdown').value = 'myValue'"`, and I can get the label of `myValue` to appear in the dropdown window, but I can't get the second dropdown to populate because it doesn't realize that I've made a selection since I'm not physically clicking on something. Is there a way to reload or refresh only `secondDropdown` (not the entire page) so that it realizes I have made a selection for `firstDropdown` and thus populate?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger `change` event of `firstDropdown` with below code using the [Event Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

`document.getElementById('firstDropdown').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the 'change' event to get the span of 'firstDropdown' to reflect that I've chosen 'myValue', but that still doesn't trigger the second dropdown to activate or populate.